# Logstash file / csv filter not working

Tags: csv, logstash

I'm trying to parse a csv file with logstash in order to load on elasticsearch. This filter works on logstash 1.4 but no after upgrade to logstash 2.3. No error given in execution, neither in debug mode, but not work.

The filter is the following

```
input {
file {
        path => "/usr/local/scripts/get_billinginfo/csv/aws-billing-detailed-line-items-with-resources-and-tags-2016-04.csv"
        start_position => beginning
        type => "billing_info"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        ignore_older => "2592000000"
    }
}



filter {
        if [type] == "billing_info" {
                csv {
                columns => [
                "InvoiceID",
                "PayerAccountId",
                "LinkedAccountId",
                "RecordType",
                "RecordId",
                "ProductName",
                "RateId",
                "SubscriptionId",
                "PricingPlanId",
                "UsageType",
                "Operation",
                "AvailabilityZone",
                "ReservedInstance",
                "ItemDescription",
                "UsageStartDate",
                "UsageEndDate",
                "UsageQuantity",
                "Rate",
                "Cost",
                "ResourceId",
                "aws_autoscaling_groupName",
                "aws_cloudformation_stack-id",
                "aws_cloudformation_stack-name",
                "user_Name",
                "user_Project"
                ]
                separator => ","
                remove_field => ["message"]
                }
                 if [InvoiceID] == "InvoiceID" {
                        drop { }
                }
                 if [RecordType] == "Rounding" {
                        drop { }
                }
                 if [RecordType] == "StatementTotal" {
                        drop { }
                }
                 if [RecordType] == "InvoiceTotal" {
                        drop { }
                }

        date {
                match => ["UsageStartDate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
        }
        mutate {
                convert => {
                        "UsageQuantity" => "float"
                        "Rate" => "float"
                        "Cost" => "float"
                        "ResourceId" => "float"
                }
                gsub => ["ProductName", " ", "_"]
                gsub => ["UsageType", "-", "_"]
                gsub => ["UsageType", "\.", "_"]
                gsub => ["aws_autoscaling_groupName", "-", "_"]
                gsub => ["aws_cloudformation_stack-id", "-", "_"]
                gsub => ["aws_cloudformation_stack-name", "-", "_"]
                gsub => ["user_Name", "-", "_"]
                gsub => ["user_Project", "-", "_"]

        }
        }
}

output {
        if [type] == "billing_info" {
        elasticsearch {
        index => "detailed-billing-aws-%{+YYYY.MM}"
                document_type => "billing_details"
                hosts => "somehost.somedomain.net"
                }

        }
}
```

No output is received, neither if i change to stdout output. Files are touched in order to be fresh, I've tried to add info at the end of the file during execution time ... Any ideas is working for me.

This logstash filter was working previously on a 1.4 logstash installation. Now i've updated to 2.3 and doesn't work.

The debug output is the following

```
Reading config file {:config_file=>"/usr/local/scripts/get_aws_billinginfo/load_billinginfo.conf", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/loader.rb", :line=>"69", :method=>"local_config"}
Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"input", :name=>"file", :path=>"logstash/inputs/file", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"76", :method=>"lookup"}
Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"codec", :name=>"plain", :path=>"logstash/codecs/plain", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"76", :method=>"lookup"}
config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@path = ["/usr/local/scripts/get_billinginfo/csv/aws-billing-detailed-line-items-with-resources-and-tags-2016-04.csv"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@start_position = "beginning" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@type = "billing_info" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@sincedb_path = "/dev/null" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@ignore_older = 2592000000 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain charset=>"UTF-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@stat_interval = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@discover_interval = 15 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@sincedb_write_interval = 15 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@delimiter = "\n" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Inputs::File/@close_older = 3600 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"filter", :name=>"csv", :path=>"logstash/filters/csv", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"76", :method=>"lookup"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@columns = ["InvoiceID", "PayerAccountId", "LinkedAccountId", "RecordType", "RecordId", "ProductName", "RateId", "SubscriptionId", "PricingPlanId", "UsageType", "Operation", "AvailabilityZone", "ReservedInstance", "ItemDescription", "UsageStartDate", "UsageEndDate", "UsageQuantity", "Rate", "Cost", "ResourceId", "aws_autoscaling_groupName", "aws_cloudformation_stack-id", "aws_cloudformation_stack-name", "user_Name", "user_Project"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@separator = "," {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@remove_field = ["message"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@add_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@remove_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@periodic_flush = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@source = "message" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@quote_char = "\"" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@autogenerate_column_names = true {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@skip_empty_columns = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::CSV/@convert = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"filter", :name=>"drop", :path=>"logstash/filters/drop", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"76", :method=>"lookup"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@add_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@remove_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@remove_field = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@periodic_flush = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@percentage = 100 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@add_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@remove_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@remove_field = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@periodic_flush = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@percentage = 100 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@add_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@remove_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@remove_field = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@periodic_flush = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@percentage = 100 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@add_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@remove_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@remove_field = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@periodic_flush = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Drop/@percentage = 100 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"filter", :name=>"date", :path=>"logstash/filters/date", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"76", :method=>"lookup"}
config LogStash::Filters::Date/@match = ["UsageStartDate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Date/@add_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Date/@remove_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Date/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Date/@remove_field = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Date/@periodic_flush = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Date/@target = "@timestamp" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Date/@tag_on_failure = ["_dateparsefailure"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"filter", :name=>"mutate", :path=>"logstash/filters/mutate", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"76", :method=>"lookup"}
config LogStash::Filters::Mutate/@convert = {"UsageQuantity"=>"float", "Rate"=>"float", "Cost"=>"float", "ResourceId"=>"float"} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Mutate/@gsub = ["ProductName", " ", "_", "UsageType", "-", "_", "UsageType", "\\.", "_", "aws_autoscaling_groupName", "-", "_", "aws_cloudformation_stack-id", "-", "_", "aws_cloudformation_stack-name", "-", "_", "user_Name", "-", "_", "user_Project", "-", "_"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Mutate/@add_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Mutate/@remove_tag = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Mutate/@add_field = {} {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Mutate/@remove_field = [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Filters::Mutate/@periodic_flush = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
Plugin not defined in namespace, checking for plugin file {:type=>"output", :name=>"elasticsearch", :path=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/plugin.rb", :line=>"76", :method=>"lookup"}
starting agent {:level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"207", :method=>"execute"}
starting pipeline {:id=>"main", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"461", :method=>"start_pipeline"}
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 4
Registering file input {:path=>["/usr/local/scripts/get_billinginfo/csv/aws-billing-detailed-line-items-with-resources-and-tags-2016-04.csv"], :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/inputs/file.rb", :line=>"171", :method=>"register"}
config LogStash::Codecs::Plain/@charset = "UTF-8" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@index = "detailed-billing-aws-%{+YYYY.MM}" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@document_type = "billing_details" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@hosts = ["172.16.230.48"] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@codec = <LogStash::Codecs::Plain charset=>"UTF-8"> {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@workers = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@manage_template = true {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@template_name = "logstash" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@template_overwrite = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@parent = nil {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@flush_size = 500 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@idle_flush_time = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@upsert = "" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@doc_as_upsert = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@max_retries = 3 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@script = "" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@script_type = "inline" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@script_lang = "" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@script_var_name = "event" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@scripted_upsert = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@retry_max_interval = 2 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@retry_max_items = 500 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@retry_on_conflict = 1 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@action = "index" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@path = "/" {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
_globbed_files: /usr/local/scripts/get_billinginfo/csv/aws-billing-detailed-line-items-with-resources-and-tags-2016-04.csv: glob is: [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"346", :method=>"_globbed_files"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@ssl_certificate_verification = true {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@sniffing = false {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
config LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch/@sniffing_delay = 5 {:level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"153", :method=>"config_init"}
Normalizing http path {:path=>"/", :normalized=>"/", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client_builder.rb", :line=>"14", :method=>"build"}
Elasticsearch HTTP client options {:hosts=>["http://172.16.230.48:9200/"], :ssl=>nil, :transport_options=>{:socket_timeout=>0, :request_timeout=>0, :proxy=>nil}, :transport_class=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::HTTP::Manticore, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb", :line=>"127", :method=>"build_client"}
Using mapping template from {:path=>nil, :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb", :line=>"6", :method=>"install_template"}
Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "omit_norms"=>true}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"analyzed", "omit_norms"=>true, "fielddata"=>{"format"=>"disabled"}}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"analyzed", "omit_norms"=>true, "fielddata"=>{"format"=>"disabled"}, "fields"=>{"raw"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"not_analyzed", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"string", "index"=>"not_analyzed"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"float"}}}}}}}, :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb", :line=>"8", :method=>"install_template"}
Found existing Elasticsearch template. Skipping template management {:name=>"logstash", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb", :line=>"30", :method=>"template_install"}
New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["172.16.230.48"], :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb", :line=>"19", :method=>"register"}
Will start workers for output {:worker_count=>1, :class=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/output_delegator.rb", :line=>"77", :method=>"register"}
Adding type with date config {:type=>nil, :field=>"UsageStartDate", :format=>"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/filters/date.rb", :line=>"301", :method=>"setupMatcher"}
Starting pipeline {:id=>"main", :pipeline_workers=>4, :batch_size=>125, :batch_delay=>5, :max_inflight=>500, :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"188", :method=>"start_workers"}
Pipeline main started {:file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"465", :method=>"start_pipeline"}
Flushing buffer at interval {:instance=>"#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::Buffer:0x73031cf0 @operations_mutex=#<Mutex:0x7dc4ece0>, @max_size=500, @operations_lock=#<Java::JavaUtilConcurrentLocks::ReentrantLock:0x79fb7780>, @submit_proc=#<Proc:0x57768928@/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.6.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:57>, @logger=#<Cabin::Channel:0xd0fdcca @metrics=#<Cabin::Metrics:0x2f6aed9c @metrics_lock=#<Mutex:0x5cd61994>, @metrics={}, @channel=#<Cabin::Channel:0xd0fdcca ...>>, @subscriber_lock=#<Mutex:0x3f8ae4ef>, @level=:debug, @subscribers={12448=>#<Cabin::Subscriber:0x346e844b @output=#<Cabin::Outputs::IO:0x589821eb @io=#<IO:fd 1>, @lock=#<Mutex:0x305d0b8b>>, @options={}>}, @data={}>, @last_flush=2016-05-11 16:01:01 +0200, @flush_interval=1, @stopping=#<Concurrent::AtomicBoolean:0x78b7799e>, @buffer=[], @flush_thread=#<Thread:0x38bbe61f run>>", :interval=>1, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/buffer.rb", :line=>"90", :method=>"interval_flush"}
Flushing buffer at interval {:instance=>"#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::Buffer:0x73031cf0 @operations_mutex=#<Mutex:0x7dc4ece0>, @max_size=500, @operations_lock=#<Java::JavaUtilConcurrentLocks::ReentrantLock:0x79fb7780>, @submit_proc=#<Proc:0x57768928@/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.6.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:57>, @logger=#<Cabin::Channel:0xd0fdcca @metrics=#<Cabin::Metrics:0x2f6aed9c @metrics_lock=#<Mutex:0x5cd61994>, @metrics={}, @channel=#<Cabin::Channel:0xd0fdcca ...>>, @subscriber_lock=#<Mutex:0x3f8ae4ef>, @level=:debug, @subscribers={12448=>#<Cabin::Subscriber:0x346e844b @output=#<Cabin::Outputs::IO:0x589821eb @io=#<IO:fd 1>, @lock=#<Mutex:0x305d0b8b>>, @options={}>}, @data={}>, @last_flush=2016-05-11 16:01:02 +0200, @flush_interval=1, @stopping=#<Concurrent::AtomicBoolean:0x78b7799e>, @buffer=[], @flush_thread=#<Thread:0x38bbe61f run>>", :interval=>1, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/buffer.rb", :line=>"90", :method=>"interval_flush"}
Flushing buffer at interval {:instance=>"#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::Buffer:0x73031cf0 @operations_mutex=#<Mutex:0x7dc4ece0>, @max_size=500, @operations_lock=#<Java::JavaUtilConcurrentLocks::ReentrantLock:0x79fb7780>, @submit_proc=#<Proc:0x57768928@/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.6.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:57>, @logger=#<Cabin::Channel:0xd0fdcca @metrics=#<Cabin::Metrics:0x2f6aed9c @metrics_lock=#<Mutex:0x5cd61994>, @metrics={}, @channel=#<Cabin::Channel:0xd0fdcca ...>>, @subscriber_lock=#<Mutex:0x3f8ae4ef>, @level=:debug, @subscribers={12448=>#<Cabin::Subscriber:0x346e844b @output=#<Cabin::Outputs::IO:0x589821eb @io=#<IO:fd 1>, @lock=#<Mutex:0x305d0b8b>>, @options={}>}, @data={}>, @last_flush=2016-05-11 16:01:03 +0200, @flush_interval=1, @stopping=#<Concurrent::AtomicBoolean:0x78b7799e>, @buffer=[], @flush_thread=#<Thread:0x38bbe61f run>>", :interval=>1, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/buffer.rb", :line=>"90", :method=>"interval_flush"}
Flushing buffer at interval {:instance=>"#<LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::Buffer:0x73031cf0 @operations_mutex=#<Mutex:0x7dc4ece0>, @max_size=500, @operations_lock=#<Java::JavaUtilConcurrentLocks::ReentrantLock:0x79fb7780>, @submit_proc=#<Proc:0x57768928@/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.6.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:57>, @logger=#<Cabin::Channel:0xd0fdcca @metrics=#<Cabin::Metrics:0x2f6aed9c @metrics_lock=#<Mutex:0x5cd61994>, @metrics={}, @channel=#<Cabin::Channel:0xd0fdcca ...>>, @subscriber_lock=#<Mutex:0x3f8ae4ef>, @level=:debug, @subscribers={12448=>#<Cabin::Subscriber:0x346e844b @output=#<Cabin::Outputs::IO:0x589821eb @io=#<IO:fd 1>, @lock=#<Mutex:0x305d0b8b>>, @options={}>}, @data={}>, @last_flush=2016-05-11 16:01:04 +0200, @flush_interval=1, @stopping=#<Concurrent::AtomicBoolean:0x78b7799e>, @buffer=[], @flush_thread=#<Thread:0x38bbe61f run>>", :interval=>1, :level=>:debug, :file=>"logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/buffer.rb", :line=>"90", :method=>"interval_flush"}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a few anonymized lines of the CSV file please?

Comment: Sorry for the delay I'm was on vacation. Sure Let me prepare !!!

Comment: Attached below can find some lines ...

Comment: You sample CSV file works fine for me on Logstash 2.3.2, there's no error and the documents get ingested just fine into my local ES 2.3.2.

Comment: Ohhh ... Not for me. I've done an upgrade from 1.4 to 2.3 ... Let me try in a fresh installation of logstash

Comment: Neither on a fresh logstash 3.2 installation ... I'm becoming crazy about that

Comment: I suggest you start with a bare config without any filters and an `stdout` output. Then add one filter at a time towards your full config and you'll quickly see where it starts itching.

Comment: finally solved !! Thanks so much for your patience !!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the root cause, and it's a bit embarrassing ... but it is.

I've made a typo on the logfile path and logstash, instead of bring an error or warning ... only wait eternally for if the file one day appear. Even with the debug mode on, no info about that the file doesn't exist is showed.

Thanks for your patience.